# I try to append chars, but i always get a gap between them

Tags: r

I try to append chars, but i always get a gap between them.

Instead of: `"ab"` i get `"a b"` for example.

I tried: `append` and `paste`.

Comment: This is because space is the default separator in function `paste` (see `?paste`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paste("a", "b")
[1] "a b"
paste("a", "b", sep="")
[1] "ab"    
paste0("a", "b")
[1] "ab"
```

Answer (score 1):

use `collapse=""`

```
paste(c("a", "b"), collapse="")
# [1] "ab"
```

or `paste0`:

```
paste0("a", "b")
# [1] "ab"
```

(which is short for `paste("a", "b", sep="")`)

Another option would be `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%s%s", "a", "b")
# [1] "ab"
```